# How to add a Table in a cell of DataGridView in C# windows application dynamically?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, windows

I am developing a windows application in C#,I have a `DataGridView`,currently showing values of a datasource. I want to add a column in which every row will have a table.Now Is there any way to do that dynamically? because the table structure will vary in each row.

thanks in advance.

**Edit :-** I mean, I want to insert a table in a cell, dynamically.

[image]

As u can see `Entity Details` column showing this when I tried to add `TableLayoutPanel`,in each row dynamically.

Comment: You will need to provide an example of what you want. As it stands it is hard to understand what you want...

Comment: Let us know if you have any questions or concerns? Cheers:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1). Try out MSDN's Mark Ridout's [TreeGridView](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/markrideout/archive/2006/01/18/new-link-for-treegridview.aspx) and read his [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/markrideout/archive/2006/01/08/customizing-the-datagridview-to-support-expanding-collapsing-ala-treegridview.aspx) on using it.

[image]

Also see if this [CodeProject DataGridView with Hierarchical Data Binding](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28276/DataGridView-with-hierarchical-data-binding) that uses  Mark Ridout's TreeGridView is useful.

2). If free controls dont work out have a look at 3rd parties (I am not affiliated with these co's):

[Devexpress XtraGrid](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Grid/data.xml)
[Telerik Gridview](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/gridview.aspx)
[Infragistics Grid](http://www.infragistics.com/products/windows-forms/grid/)
[VIBlend DataGridView for WinForms](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5f0d8caa-3587-44d9-9491-5fb3d5b6b8d0)
[Janus Grid](http://www.janusys.com/janus/library/CustomPages/gridexnet.htm)
[xceed's Grid](http://xceed.com/Grid_WinForms_Intro.html)

---

3). I'm pretty sure adding a TablePanelLayout into a Grids cell is **not** what you want, here is the code so you can see how dodgy it is for yourself:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("name");
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
{
    dt.Rows.Add("");
}
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 200;
//add tableLayoutPanel1 into the control collection of the DataGridView
this.dataGridView1.Controls.Add(tableLayoutPanel1);
//resize the row
this.dataGridView1.Rows[1].Height = 100;
//set its location and size to fit the cell
tableLayoutPanel1.Location = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0,1, true).Location;
tableLayoutPanel1.Size = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, 1, true).Size;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is this article : [How to: Host Controls in Windows Forms DataGridView Cells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx)

at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx)

The DataGridView control provides several column types, enabling your users to enter and edit values in a variety of ways. 
If these column types do not meet your data-entry needs, ***however, you can create your own column types with cells that host controls of your choosing***.

To do this, you must define ***classes that derive from DataGridViewColumn and DataGridViewCell***.

You must also define a class that derives from Control and ***implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl*** interface.

So i would recommend , first Make your Table as independent control with properties or method 
then use that control to be displayed for each row - when you are doing databind ,let each row set data for your TableControl.

An ***alternative approach*** could be this (assuming you are not editing in grid) - you can create a single row like usercontrol ( create a usercontrol where all textbox or label are laid around like datagridrow style them so that it looks like a single row) and then you add them in a panel with scrollbar .

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is (easily) possible with the controls provided out-of-the-box by Microsoft.

If you have the budget, perhaps check out Telerik's controls.

http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/gridview.aspx

They have a gridview control as part of their .NET WinForm controls that looks like it will do what you want it to.

Otherwise, is it possible to change your architecture and do an ASP.NET web-based approach to solving this problem?

Hope that helps. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a column with a table within it in a `DataGridView` is not possible according to me..
Best alternate to your question is to create a dynamic table by self and repeat rows to show your data and within that row you can off course put a cell with a table within it.

Comment: `We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise.` I just showed it is possible...

Answer (score 0):

You can add a table to the cells control collection using the RowDatabound Event. Something like this example(sorry - different to what you are doing but maybe similar to what you want, also in VB rather than C#)

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    Dim i As Integer

    Dim myTable As Table
    Dim myRow As TableRow
    Dim mycell As TableCell
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        myTable = New Table
        myRow = New TableRow
        For i = 1 To 3
            mycell = New TableCell
            mycell.Text = i.ToString
            mycell.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid
            mycell.BorderWidth = 0.2
            mycell.Width = 15
            If i = 1 Then mycell.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Beige
            If i = 2 Then mycell.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Yellow
            If i = 3 Then mycell.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Green
            myRow.Cells.Add(mycell)
        Next
        myTable.Rows.Add(myRow)
        e.Row.Cells(12).Controls.Add(myTable)
    End If
End Sub
```